# Tomcat generates empty access log file

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, web-applications, configuration

Since I need the runtime information of every request processed by Tomcat, I've configured the access log output for Tomcat in the file `{$CATALINA_HOME}/conf/server.xml` as following. But when running the application, the access log file just stays empty. Anybody knows the reasons? Thanks a lot!

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="deploy"
    unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

    <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
         Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
              directory="/home/admin/shopcenter/logs/"
              prefix="localhost_access_log"
              suffix=".log"
              buffered="false"
              encoding="GB18030"
              pattern="common"/>

</Host>
```

Comment: checked var folder?

Comment: @CommonMan Do you mean the /var folder? I didn't find a access log file there...

Comment: var, has logs, check your configuration then.

Comment: Does it work without the `encoding` property?

Comment: @Selaron No...Tomcat doesn't output access logs with or without the encoding property.

Comment: @CommonMan Could you please be more specific? I cannot find any relative logs in the /var/log directory, is it the location you mean? And what configuration I need to check then?

Comment: Does it output exceptions while starting? (in catalina.log or console)

Comment: @Selaron No, Tomcat starts successfully.

Comment: @CommonMan No, I'm using command line scripts in a linux server.

Comment: Have you checked with the other Tomcat versions?? Try with other versions if you haven't.

Comment: @CommonMan Sadly I cannot change the version of Tomcat in my environment. Are there any other solutions I can try?

Comment: Which Tomcat version do you run?

Comment: @Igor 8.5.37.1327.